# How to apply trained classifier to entire Landsat collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, land-cover, land-classification

I have classified the 2019 image using Google Earth Engine. How can I use the training data and code I have for 2019 and apply it from 1984 to 2018 instead of training/running a code for each image individually.

Link to my script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/15fc51687216911cfdf7d3c8c184938f

Answer (score 1):

You can create your 1984-2018 images and classify each of them using the classifier you trained on the 2019 data:

```
var classified1984 = image1984.select(bands).classify(classifier)
```

If there's a lot of training data and/or there goes a lot of processing into your images, you might be better off exporting them as assets before training/classifying.

If you would be using the cart() classifier, you could store the decision tree>

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
   features: training_subset,
   classProperty: 'landcover',
   inputProperties: bands
});

var treeString = classifier.explain().get('tree')
print(treeString)
```

Later on, you can use the decision tree to create a classifier without training it again:

```
var classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTree(treeString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question while searching for the same question. Did you ever find code to use training data from the present to classify the past? I tried messing around with the above suggestion, but it's missing too much for my beginner skills to figure out...